# Autoincrement-like field for objects with the same foreign key (Django 1.8, MySQL 5.5)

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I've got a Django model (let's call it ObjectLog), many of which are related to a single Object by a foreign key.  See below for a brief definition:

```
class ObjectLog(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created','-N']
        unique_together = ("object","N")
    object = models.ForeignKey(Object, null=False)                                                                                                                                                              
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    issuer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    N = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

Each ObjectLog which is related to a single Object should have a unique N value (as shown by the `unique_together` requirement).  Another way of putting this is that N should essentially be an autoincrement field, but only relative to the ObjectLog set for an individual Object. This is not a difficult thing to accomplish logically with a custom save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                        
    with transaction.atomic():
        logs = self.object.objectlog_set.select_for_update().order_by('-N')
        if logs:
            self.N = logs[0].N + 1
        else:
            self.N = 1
        super(ObjectLog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, I'm having trouble dealing with concurrency. When multiple processes are simultaneously trying to create ObjectLogs for a single Object, they often end up with the same value of N, resulting in errors like "Duplicate entry \'249244-169\' for key".  I've tried to deal with this by using `transaction.atomic` and `select_for_update` in my `save` method, although I'm now realizing that atomicity is not really the property that will help me here.  It looks like I need some way of locking the rows in the ObjectLog table related to the Object in question while the code determines what N should be and saves the new row, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I'm using Django 1.8 and MySQL 5.5 with a MyISAM engine.  I've also tried modifying the table in question to use InnoDB.  When using InnoDB, I get errors like "1213, \'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction\'".  So it seems as though locking is working in this scenario, but maybe I'm overdoing it?  A nasty solution would be to catch these errors and use a while loop to force the save method to retry, but I'd really rather not.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!  Apologies if I've misused some terminology, I'm fairly new to the scene.  I'm happy to provide more information if I've missed something of importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by constructing and executing a raw SQL query to do the autoincrement and insertion in a single database transaction.  I spent a lot of time poring through the Django source code to understand how their default model save method works so that I could do this as robustly as possible.  However, I fully expect that this will need to be modified for non-MySQL backends.

First, I created an abstract class which ObjectLog will now derive from, which features this new save method:

```
class AutoIncrementModel(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract class used as a base for classes which need the
    autoincrementing save method described below.
    """
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, auto_field, auto_fk, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Arguments:
            auto_field: name of field which acts as an autoincrement field.
            auto_fk:    name of ForeignKey to which the auto_field is relative.
        """

        # Do normal save if this is not an insert (i.e., the instance has a
        # primary key already).
        meta = self.__class__._meta
        pk_set = self._get_pk_val(meta) is not None
        if pk_set:
            super(ObjectLog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            return

        # Otherwise, we'll generate some raw SQL to do the
        # insert and auto-increment.

        # Get model fields, except for primary key field.
        fields = meta.local_concrete_fields
        if not pk_set:
            fields = [f for f in fields if not
                isinstance(f, models.fields.AutoField)]

        # Setup for generating base SQL query for doing an INSERT.
        query = models.sql.InsertQuery(self.__class__._base_manager.model)
        query.insert_values(fields, objs=[self])
        compiler = query.get_compiler(using=self.__class__._base_manager.db)
        compiler.return_id = meta.has_auto_field and not pk_set

        fk_name = meta.get_field(auto_fk).column
        with compiler.connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Get base SQL query as string.
            for sql, params in compiler.as_sql():
                # compiler.as_sql() looks like:
                # INSERT INTO `table_objectlog` VALUES (%s,...,%s)
                # We modify this to do:
                # INSERT INTO `table_objectlog` SELECT %s,...,%s FROM
                # `table_objectlog` WHERE `object_id`=id
                # NOTE: it's unlikely that the following will generate
                # a functional database query for non-MySQL backends.

                # Replace VALUES (%s, %s, ..., %s) with
                # SELECT %s, %s, ..., %s
                sql = re.sub(r"VALUES \((.*)\)", r"SELECT \1", sql)

                # Add table to SELECT from and ForeignKey id corresponding to
                # our autoincrement field.
                sql += " FROM `{tbl_name}` WHERE `{fk_name}`={fk_id}".format(
                    tbl_name=meta.db_table,
                    fk_name=fk_name,
                    fk_id=getattr(self, fk_name)
                    )

                # Get index corresponding to auto_field.
                af_idx = [f.name for f in fields].index(auto_field)
                # Put this directly in the SQL. If we use parameter
                # substitution with cursor.execute, it gets quoted
                # as a literal, which causes the SQL command to fail.
                # We shouldn't have issues with SQL injection because
                # auto_field should never be a user-defined parameter.
                del params[af_idx]
                sql = re.sub(r"((%s, ){{{0}}})%s".format(af_idx),
                r"\1IFNULL(MAX({af}),0)+1", sql, 1).format(af=auto_field)

                # IFNULL(MAX({af}),0)+1 is the autoincrement SQL command,
                # {af} is substituted as the column name.

                # Execute SQL command.
                cursor.execute(sql, params)

            # Get primary key from database and set it in memory.
            if compiler.connection.features.can_return_id_from_insert:
                id = compiler.connection.ops.fetch_returned_insert_id(cursor)
            else:
                id = compiler.connection.ops.last_insert_id(cursor,
                    meta.db_table, meta.pk.column)
            self._set_pk_val(id)

            # Refresh object in memory in order to get auto_field value.
            self.refresh_from_db()
```

Then the ObjectLog model uses this like:

```
class ObjectLog(AutoIncrementModel):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created','-N']
        unique_together = ("object","N")
    object = models.ForeignKey(Object, null=False)                                                                                                                                                              
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    issuer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    N = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Set up to call save method of the base class (AutoIncrementModel)
        kwargs.update({'auto_field': 'N', 'auto_fk': 'event'})
        super(EventLog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This allows calls to ObjectLog.save() to still work as expected.