# How can you add a secondary ID for a model, based on its association with a particular object?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

Example code:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  ...

class Comment(models.Model):
  ...
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments',
                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
  post_comment_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, null=False)
```

Imagine a blog post with a bunch of comments underneath it. I want to assign a secondary ID to each one of these comments, representing the relationship between the comment and the blog post - for example: Comment #1: ..., Comment #2: ..., etc etc.

I don't want to do this on the frontend because, for example, if comment #2 is ever deleted, I don't want to assign another comment associated with this particular blog post the #2 ID again.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Django does not allow having more than one `AutoField` within the same model (and the first one is already used by the `id` field). You can create a separate counter table for keeping track of `post+comment_id` pairs and override the `save()` method to get the next comment id for that post. That would probably result in a race condition though, so also investigate row locking.

Comment: @Selcuk would it be possible for you to please show me an example - or point me to a resource - for doing this with row locking?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265818/autoincrement-like-field-for-objects-with-the-same-foreign-key-django-1-8-mysq)

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks so much! I've been searching all day and thought I saw just about every question related to this on stackoverflow but somehow missed that one. If you like, feel free to add something as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: If it looks like you have found your answer there, you can mark this one as a duplicate so that future readers can also be referred to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is removing the post number field and adding a timestamp field or date added field. By using this timestamp you can still obtain all the comments for a particular post in order. If you still want to have IDs you can maintain an auto increment ID field also.

```
class Post(models.Model):
...

class Comment(models.Model):
...
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments',
                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Another solution is:

```
class Post(models.Model):
...

class Comment(models.Model):
...
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments',
                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    post_comment_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1) 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            last_comment = self.post.comment_set.all().orderby('-post_comment_number')[0]
        except KeyError:  # When there are no comments
            pass
        else:
            Comment.objects.filter(id=self.id).update(post_comment_number=last_comment.post_comment_number+1)
        return obj
```

But like [Selcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011147/selcuk) mentioned this may result in a race condition. I prefer the workaround over this solution.

Comment: I want to avoid the second solution because of the race condition issue. As for the first solution, the workaround, I can see how using the timestamp could help but that leaves a major problem. I can use the timestamp to give each comment a number under each post - like comment #1, #2, #3 based on their creation dates; however, if, say, comment #2 is deleted then comment #3 now becomes comment #2. I want to avoid that from happening. I don't want the "number" of any deleted comment to ever be assigned to another comment. Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks so much!